# Event on Edit excecute once but affect twice

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

On Google sheet I have an event that deletes a row if certain conditions are meet.

But sometimes it deletes two rows.

On each excecution of OnEdit I validate if it is the right sheet, the rigth column, and the expected value to procede.

Looking at logs, it only runs once.

```
/** @OnlyCurrentDoc */

function onEdit(e)
{   
  Logger.log("TESTING TESTING ON EDIT");
  if(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetName() == "Student Info")
  {
    Logger.log("Enter Student Info");
    //Obtenemos donde  se ha realizado el cambio
    var range = e.range;

    //var targetSheet = app.getActiveSpreadsheet.getSheetByName("Archive");

    //targetSheet.appendRow();


    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var s = e.source.getActiveSheet();
    var r = e.source.getActiveRange();



    if(s.getName() == "Student Info" && r.getColumn() == 8 && r.getValue() == 'Archive') {
      var id= s.getRange(r.getRow(),1).getValue();
      r.setValue('');
      Logger.log("Get ID");
      var row = r.getRow();
      var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
      var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Archive");
      var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
      s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target);

      Logger.log("Prior to delete ROW in student info");
      Logger.log(row);
      s.deleteRow(row);
      Logger.log("After Deleting ROW  in student info");


      //Student Tracker
      var st=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Student Tracker")

      for (i=6;i<=st.getLastRow();i++)
      {
        if (st.getRange(i, 1).getValue()==id)
        {
                Logger.log("Prior Deleting ROW  in student tracker");
                st.deleteRow(i);
                Logger.log("After Deleting ROW  in student tracker");
          break;
        }
      }       
      //

      //SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Upwork Request").getRange(range.getRow(),7).setValue(id);
    } else
    {Logger.log("Not  Student Info Or Archive");}
    // SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Upwork Request").getRange(range.getRow(),8).setValue(new Date());

  } else
  {     Logger.log("No Student Info");}
}
```

No error messages, just sometimes deleted two rows.

**EDIT:**

I just notice in the event log that not only runs twice but it does not finish
I added a log after break that is never hit

**EDIT2**
After user correction on for statement, it still running twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

I believe this line `for (i=6;i++;st.getLastRow())`
Should be something like this `for (i=6;i<=st.getLastRow();i++) {`

```
function onEdit(e) {   
  var sh=e.range.getSheet();
  var ss = e.source;
  if(sh.getName() == "Student Info") {
    if(e.range.columnStart==8 && e.value=='Archive') {
      var id=sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart,1).getValue();
      e.range.setValue('');
      var tsh=ss.getSheetByName("Archive");
      var trg=tsh.getRange(tsh.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
      sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart, 1, 1, tsh.getLastColumn()).moveTo(trg);
      sh.deleteRow(e.range.rowStart);
      var st=SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Student Tracker");
      for (i=6;i<=st.getLastRow();i++) {
        if (st.getRange(i, 1).getValue()==id) {
          st.deleteRow(i);
          return
        }
      }       
    }
  }
  return;
}
```

Comment: sure, thanks! but still running twice. How could I made changes without triggering again, or how could I flag this without global variables. I changed the value in the cell, but it stil entering, not sure what to do.

Comment: Are you actually calling the function onEdit() ?

Comment: Have you also created a trigger of your you own?

Comment: If you answer yes to both above questions, then rename the function something unique like `uniquefunc` and delete your trigger and create another for `unique func`

Comment: cooper both true, Will do, but I cant follow the logic. Actually, I removed the trigger, but used the same name. Is it a reserved name onEdit(e)?? prety new to GAS. Thanks

Comment: Well, I think you were getting two triggers. One simple trigger and one installable trigger.You must change the name because onEdit() fires off of a simple trigger.

Comment: Ok, it is working now, thanks. Would it be faster removing the trigger and calling the function onEdit? There is a noticebly delay

Comment: I was guessing that you getting two triggers on simple and one installable.